# Raspberry pi and arduino serial connection over usb displays USB information

Tags: python, arduino

I was trying to talk between the Arduino and raspberry pi using USB, with the pySerial library. I wanted to have multiple sensors sending in data and a couple of command sent from the pi's side. I've tried arrays to send data and use indexing on the python (receiving) side to access individual data channels, is there another way to do this task, I've tried learning about "data.split(':')", I don't seem to understand how it works. Could someone please show me a legal method to transfer data to-fro?

Arduino Code:

```
int data[100];
int val2 = A0;
int val1 = A1;

void setup(){
  pinMode(val1, INPUT);
  pinMode(val2, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
 // individual channels of data transmitted, delya = 60 for 6 channels, f = 1/50
  while(1){
    data[0] = analogRead(val2);
    data[1] = analogRead(val1);
    data[2] = analogRead(A2);
    data[4] = analogRead(A3);
    data[5] = analogRead(A4);
    Serial.print(data[0]);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(data[1]);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(data[2]);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(data[3]);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(data[4]);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(data[5]);

    Serial.println();
    delay(60);
  }

}
```

Python side:

```
import serial
from  Tkinter import *
import time

data = []
newData = []
next = []
root = Tk()
while True:
    ardu = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout = 0.1)
    data =ardu.readline()       
    print data[0:25]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you need Python's `split()` method. You can use it as follows:

#### Arduino Code:

```
int data[6];
int val2 = A0;
int val1 = A1;

void setup(){
  pinMode(val1, INPUT);
  pinMode(val2, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
 // individual channels of data transmitted, delay = 60 for 6 channels, f = 1/50
  while(1){
    data[0] = analogRead(val2);
    data[1] = analogRead(val1);
    data[2] = analogRead(A2);
    data[3] = analogRead(A3);
    data[4] = analogRead(A4);
    data[5] = analogRead(A5);
    Serial.print(data[0]);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(data[1]);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(data[2]);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(data[3]);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(data[4]);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(data[5]);

    Serial.println();
    delay(60);
  }

}
```

#### Python side:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while True:
    line = ser.readline().decode("utf-8").strip('\n').strip('\r')  # remove newline and carriage return characters
    print "Received: '{}'".format(line)
    data = line.split(':')
    for i in range(len(data)):
        print "data[{}]".format(i), data[i]
```

#### Results:

```
Received: '495:916:837:37:120'
data[0] 495
data[1] 916
data[2] 837
data[3] 37
data[4] 120
```

#### Explanation:

`split()` creates a list from a string, the elements of the list are the parts of the string between two pairs of `:`, or between the start/end and another `:`.

Comment: ahh i see, quite precise though :) But is it also possible to use the usual indexing method?

Comment: @PrathikGurudatt, you can only index it once you've used `split()`. Mark as accepted if it has helped you.

Comment: Thank-you, Morgoth - I was looking for the code to cleanup the Arduino print output received on the Pi side Your decode("utf-8").strip('\n').strip('\r') does a nice job succinctly :-)  The split implementation is a bonus for me !